# How to select objects which has an array size=0 in Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate and I have something like:

```
public class Product{
  private Integer id;
  private List<Price> prices;

  // getters and setters
}

public class Price{
  private Integer id;
  private Double price;
  private Product product;
  private List<Recipe> recipes;

  // getters and setters
}

public class Recipe{
  private Integer q;

  //getters and setters
}
```

I'm wondering if I can do something like:

```
List<Product> products = session.createQuery(
    "select product from Price p"
    + " inner join p.recipes where p.recipes = null ").list();
```

I want to select all the products from prices which doesn't have any recipe

Answer (score 0):

```
session.createCriteria(Product.class).createAlias("prices", "prices")
            .createAlias("prices.recipes", "recipes", Criteria.LEFT_JOIN)
            .add(Restrictions.isNull("recipes.id"))
            .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```

Comment: Hi, I've tried your solution but I Criteria.LEFT_JOIN es deprecated so I replaced it with JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN but I'm still getting all the products. The restriction is not working.

session.createCriteria(Product.class)
.createAlias("prices", "prices")
.createAlias("prices.recipes", "recipes", "recipes", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
 .add(Restrictions.isNull("recipes.id"))         .setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();